# email.message.set_content('') not working and email shows no body

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am using `smtplib` to send emails and `email.message` to give it values. As it sends the email, all the attachments and subject are received but there is no body message. I tried printing the `message` before `msg.set_content = message` and it was fine.

---

Here is my code:

> ```
> import smtplib
> from email.message import EmailMessage
>
> msg = EmailMessage()
> msg['from'] = from_email -> variable
> msg['to'] = to_email
> msg['subject'] = subject
> msg.set_content = message
>
> server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
> server.ehlo()
> server.starttls()  
> server.login(from_email, from_pass)
> server.send_message(msg)
> server.close()
> ```

Comment: what's the content of the variable `message`? where are you specifying content for the `body`?

Comment: The variable message here is just a string.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
msg.set_content = message
```

to

```
msg.set_content(message)
```

That's because `set_content` is a method, not an attribute, so by setting a value to it you're replacing the method itself with the content and not setting the content.